# jQuery regex test in .each error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Ok, so I have multiple inputs that receive UUID codes. So Im using the .each function from jQuery to go one by one and validate the input to be a UUID code. So this is the code that I have until now:

```
function validateAll(){
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/ig;
    $('input.offer').each(function(x){
        if($(this).val() !== ""){
            console.log(x+" - "+$(this).val()+" - "+regex.test($(this).val()));
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Now when I run this with two inputs being: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 this is what I get in the console:

0 - 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - true

1 - 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - false

Why the regex.test() is validating the first one but not second one? Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H7v5n/

Comment: moving the regexp declaration to inside the .each fixes it, but i'm curious as to why that matters. http://jsfiddle.net/H7v5n/1/

Comment: removing the g modifier worked :) thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

You need to bring the regex instantiation within the loop - it cannot be retested against another string.

```
function validateAll(){
    $('input.offer').each(function(x) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/ig;
        if($(this).val() !== ""){
            console.log(x + " - " + $(this).val() + " - " + regex.test($(this).val()));
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LtNT4/)

The reason the second iteration fails:

> when [the regex] is a global regular expression. It will attempt to match from the index of the last match in any previous string.

Article: [Be careful when reusing regex objects](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2011/11/careful-when-reusing-javascript-regexp.html)

Comment: So the simpler solution is to remove the `g` modifier.

Comment: True, although I assumed that the OP had used that for a purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any purpose to the `g` modifier when using `.test()`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `g` modifier from the regexp. When you reuse a regexp with this modifier, it starts the new test from the index of the last match, rather than the beginning of the new string. This modifier serves no purpose when using `Regex::test`, since it only tells you if the regexp matches anywhere -- multiple matches are redundant. So it should be:

```
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$/i;
```

Also, I wonder why you put both `a-z` and `A-Z` in your character classes when you also use the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/H7v5n/3/)

Comment: Thanks Barmar I removed the g modifier and fixed the regex thanks :)